# EF6, refreshing large DB-first entity model taking forever in VS 2015 on Windows 10, compared to VS 2015 on Windows 8.1

Tags: entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Ever since I upgraded to Windows 10 my entity model has been nearly impossible to update.  It takes forever to open the model designer, then forever to right click the designer to bring up the context menu to select "Update model from database".  Opening the same model in VS 2015 but on Windows 8.1 is much, much faster.  It doesn't seem to be just my machine since the same is happening for our other developers on Windows 10.  But those on Windows 8.1 have no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue, and resolved it by doing the following:

- Navigate to Tools > Options > General
- Untick "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance"
- Untick "Use graphics acceleration if available"

Though you may not have to, I left "Enable rich client visual experience" unticked.

There's also another user who is having this issue, for whom the aforementioned fix does not help, it might be worth keeping an eye on their post, too, to see if anyone has any further ideas. I've included a link to their question below. :)

[Entity Framework edmx click on diagram very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854875/entity-framework-edmx-click-on-diagram-very-slow/33884465)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question. The accepted answer there was exactly what was needed and may help you and @user2341060

Comment: Sadly this didn't work for me, and neither did any of the ideas in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just summarising the hard work of others here in case you, like me, find this question first.

**Touch screens** seem to suffer from this issue.  (E.g. my HP Envy laptop takes a long time to load our company's .EDMX, while my colleague's largely inferior laptop opens it quickly.)  The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854875/entity-framework-edmx-click-on-diagram-very-slow/33884465) contained in XtraSimplicity's answer was what helped me.

The idea is to kill the Windows background process associated with the touchscreen "stuff" (technical term meaning "I have no idea").  It may go by one of these names:

- Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel
- TabletInputService
- TabTip.exe

You can also stop it from rearing its ugly head again by disabling the service.